# MVVMCross 6.0.1 Dependency Injection not working

Tags: mvvmcross

I am trying to get my Xamarin Forms MvvmCross6 working correctly, and have been banging my head for hours and am frustrated. I'm sure this is probably something stupid that I am doing incorrectly. Currently, I have been trying to follow the example here: https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2018/04/13/MVX=0F-A-first-MvvmCross-Application-(MVX1-days-of-MvvmCross).aspx

I'm trying to get the constructor level dependency injection to work. In my App.cs (core project) I have:

```
public override void Initialize()
    {
        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Client")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserDialogs>(() => UserDialogs.Instance);

        RegisterCustomAppStart<AppStart<LoginViewModel>>();
    }
```

In the core project AppStart.cs, I have the following

```
public class AppStart<TViewModel> : MvxAppStart<TViewModel> where TViewModel : IMvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _mvxNavigationService;

    public AppStart(IMvxApplication app, IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService)
        : base(app, mvxNavigationService)
    {
        _mvxNavigationService = mvxNavigationService;
    }

    protected override void NavigateToFirstViewModel(object hint)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate<LoginViewModel>();
    }
}
```

In my LoginViewModel (also in core)
I have:

```
 public class LoginViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
      private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
      private readonly IUserDialogs _userDialogs;
      public LoginViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService, IUserDialogs userDialogs)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _userDialogs = userDialogs;
        }
```

When I debug the code, I get Object reference run-time error. I can only get this to run correctly if I remove IUserDialogs from the constructor (as well as the _userDialogs = userDialogs from the constructor body)

Here is a link to my github repository for my sample project playground code.
https://github.com/danielPollack/ToolboxMvvmCross6Forms

I realize MVVMCross6 has only been out for a few weeks, and this is probably something really stupid on my part. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not overriding AppStart like this. For example you don't block the navigation, so it continues before finishing the setup. This might cause things in a bad state. Use:

`RegisterAppStart<LoginViewModel>();`